# Заполнение массива случайным образом

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Нужно заполнить массив случайным образом в заданном промежутке: элемент добавляется в массив при нажатии на кнопку «ОК». Добавить сортировку по убыванию.

```
<div id="d">
 Длина<input type="text" id="lenght">
 Мин<input type="text" id="min">
 Макс<input type="text" id="max">
 <button @click="rand()">Ок</button>
 <div id="out"></div>
</div>
<script src="js/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:"#d",
        data:{
            lenght,
            min,
            max,
            result:[],
        },
        methods:{
           rand(){
            for(i=0;i<length;i++)
               {
                   result.push(randomInteger(min,max))
               }
               function randomInteger(min,max){
                let rand=min-0.5+Math.random()*(max-min+1);
                rand=Math.round(rand);
                return rand
                console.log(rand)
               }  
           }
        }
       })
```

Comment: А у вас код компелируется?

Comment: Посмотрите на свое условие цикла внимательно.

Comment: js еше может i сделать var без строгого режима но буквы перемешать никак нет